# Why are parameters of an agent empty after creation and sending it to another agent?

Tags: nullpointerexception, exit, send, anylogic, agent

In my Anylogic model I have agents (`carriers`) that receive `orders` and after some delay processes, should create a new `truckOrder` and send it to a `truck` agent. I have coded it in the exit block as you can see in the figure below. When running, I get a `NullPointerException` error within this exit block, because `order.terminal` and `order.customer` are empty.

[image]

This is how an `order` is created (within a `customer` agent) and send to the enter block of a `carrier`:

```
Order order = new Order(this, main.terminals(0));
Carrier carrier = randomFrom(main.carriers);
if (carrier != null)
    carrier.receiveOrder.take(order);
```

Also when I do it differently, like below, it does not work. Does anybody know why?

```
Order order = new Order(this, main.terminals(1));
Carrier carrier = randomFrom(main.carriers);
if (carrier != null)        
    send(order, carrier.receiveOrder);
```

The `NullPointerException` error is placed within these rows of the `Carrier.java` tab:

[image]

Comment: It seems either `order.terminal` or `order.customer` is `null`. Can you put `traceln(order.terminal)` and `traceln(order.customer)` at the beginning of On exit cell and tell us the output?

Comment: They are printed in the console where the error message appears..just check the lines above the NullPointerException after running....

Comment: Now it gets a `NullPointerException` error at the row of the `traceln`

Comment: Yes, but in which traceln line exactly? Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: In the line `traceln(order.terminal);` which was the first line (I also posted the screenshot in my question)

Comment: It means your order agent is problematic. It has no terminal defined.

Comment: @YasharAhmadov Do you know why? I added in my question how the order is created (with terminal and customer..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spurious `order` Variable in Carrier.

You are creating the type Order agent in Customer and passing it to the Enter block of Carrier. Thus (assuming you set the Enter block so that its "Agent type" is `Order`) you should be referring to it via the keyword `agent` in your block actions. (This keyword refers to the agent that is currently passing through the block, which is your Order agent.)

Thus you should be using `agent.terminal` and `agent.customer` NOT `order.terminal` and `order.customer` (which are referring to your variable in Carrier which probably hasn't been set to anything).

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed this and it is working now :)